# Slack is printing raw JSON instead of styled message

Tags: php, slack-api

I am working on a Slack slash command in PHP that takes a Twitter username and returns that person's latest tweet.

I can't figure out how to display the user's profile image to make it look as nice as Slack's Twitter integration.

The issue it seems to me is that I have to include 'unfurl_media: true' in JSON that gets sent back to Slack. That means I can't just use `echo` to print out the Twitter data I want, which is in an associative array.

I tried grabbing the Twitter data I want from the associative array, encoding it again in JSON and then printing that. But all that does is print the JSON as plain text. I checked a JSON validator and it says what gets printed to Slack is valid JSON, so I don't understand why slack isn't converting it to a styled message.

Any suggestions?

Here's the code. It's frankencode pulled from a bunch of different places that I am trying to bend to my will.

```
<?php

require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$command = $_POST['command'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$token = $_POST['token'];

if($token != '[insert your Slack slash command token here]'){ 
$msg = ":squirrel: The token for the slash command doesn't match. We're done    here until IT fixes it. Don't worry, Squirrelock is on the case.";
die($msg);
echo $msg;
}


$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "[insert access token here]",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "[insert access token secret here]",
'consumer_key' => "[insert consumer key here]",
'consumer_secret' => "[insert consumer secret here]"
);

$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

$requestMethod = "GET";

$getfield = '?screen_name='.$text.'&count=1';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                          ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                          ->performRequest(), $assoc = TRUE);

foreach($string as $items)
{
$reply = "".$items['user']['profile_image_url']." *".$items['user'] ['name']."* ".$items['user']['screen_name']. "\n ".$items['text']."\n  ".$items['created_at']."";
}

$data = json_encode(array(
"response_type" => "in_channel",
"text" => $reply,
"unfurl_media" => true,
"unfurl_links" => true

));

echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: "I checked a JSON validator and it says what gets printed to Slack is valid JSON, so I don't understand why slack isn't converting it to a styled message." Could you give an example of the JSON you're sending to Slack and what you expect Slack to do with that JSON?

Comment: Here's an example. I want Slack to convert this JSON into a formatted message. If you plop this into [Slack's Message Builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/formatting/builder) it will render (still need to work on styling after I get it to render).  But for some reason this doesn't work on Slack itself. {"response_type":"in_channel","text": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/462698461792456704\/IkB137SH_normal.png ​*Ian Paul*​ ianpaul\n Cortana is so great when it's not crashing, which isn't often.\n Tue Jun 14 06:01:06 +0000 2016","unfurl_media":"true","unfurl_links":"true"}

Comment: JSON one more time in a clearer format @smarx . `{"response_type":"in_channel","text": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/462698461792456704\/IkB137SH_normal.png ​*Ian Paul*​ ianpaul\n Cortana is so great when it's not crashing, which isn't often.\n Tue Jun 14 06:01:06 +0000 2016","unfurl_media":"true","unfurl_links":"true"}`

Comment: Try `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `echo $data;`?

Comment: Yep! Adding the header worked perfectly! Thanks @smarx ! I don't understand this, actually, because I tried adding a header earlier and it didn't do a thing. I've spent hours on this problem so it's all a little fuzzy right now, but I may have changed a few things in the `$data` variable to correct some JSON output and didn't try adding a header again. Anyway, now it works! Thanks so much!

Comment: I also simplified the JSON sent to slack by only including the url for the latest Twitter post in the `$data` array. Then with properly formatted JSON and the header the Twitter integration took over and styled it for me! Bonus!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving my comment down to an answer, since it seems to have fixed the problem:

Add `header('Content-Type: application/json');` before `echo $data;`. The issue is that Slack is interpreting your response as text. It will interpret it as JSON only if the `Content-Type` is correct.